# I'm creating new Attribute for Category and facing an issue in Magento 2.X

Tags: magento-2.1, category-attribute, upgradeschema

My Upgrade Script :

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    private $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory, EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        //handle all possible upgrade versions

        if(!$context->getVersion()) {
        //no previous version found, installation, InstallSchema was just executed
        //be careful, since everything below is true for installation !
        }

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2') < 0)
        {
            //code to upgrade to 1.0.2
            $installer = $setup;

            $installer->startSetup();

            $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);

            $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

            $categorySetup->removeAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'my_attribute`enter code here`' );

            $categorySetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'my_attribute', [
                     'type' => 'int',
                     'label' => 'MyAttribute',
                     'input' => 'select',
                     'source' => 'MyCompany\MyModule\Model\Api\Category\Attributeset',
                     'required' => false,
                     'sort_order' => 1,
                     'visible'       => 1,
                     'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                     'group' => 'General',
                ]
            );

            $installer->endSetup();
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
 }
 ?>
```

After `setup:upgrade` I Got error in composer:

> Fatal Error: Declaration of
>   MyCompany\Mymodule\Setup\UpgradeSchema::upgrade() must be compatible
>   with Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface::upgrade()

Answer (score 3):

add `use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface`